# MASM using registers as expressions between mod operator

Tags: masm, masm32

I am completely newbie in masm32 and I want to realize such idea which is described in following line of (incorrect) code :

> mov ebx,(eax mod any_number)

Compiler gives me error A2026 : constant expected

I read that mod operation cannot be used between registers, so which methods will help me to perform same idea ?

Hope for your help.

Comment: I want just to get modula from the value saved in the register eax and some number , but I cannot use registers with the mod operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9 % 5 = 4
What does Modulus mean?  It is the remainder after you divide 2 numbers

```
    mov     eax, 9 mod 5
```

or

```
xor     edx, edx
mov     eax, 9
mov     ecx, 5
div     ecx
```

now edx contain the Modulus

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use my answer to exercise 2.b of the book *Guide to Assembly Language: A Concise Introduction by James T. Streib*,

```
;result = number % amount

mov eax,number  
cdq             ;copy or propagate the sign bit into the edx register
idiv amount     
mov result,edx  ;the remainder in the edx register and the  
                ;quotient in the eax register
```